# horizontal and vertical invisible scroll on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to hide the scrollbars and make horizontal scroll on button press that would scroll one column to a desired direction.

But sadly can't seem to get it to work.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEEcR.png)

```js
$('#left-button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.row-fluid').animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=200px"
  }, "slow");
});

$('#right-button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.row-fluid').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=200px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
.row-fluid {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.row-fluid .col-lg-4 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 700px;
}

.image-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="overflow: auto">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="left-button">left</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="right-button">right</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
      <a href="" class="image-wrapper"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS I want to use bootstrap because eventually it will be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should think of this as a slider/carousel. You would need (in hierarchical order):

1. A container with `overflow-x: hidden; position: relative`.
2. A wrapper for the content, that moves within the container (`position: absolute` + [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/%20%22jQuery%20animate) on left/right CSS property, or even [CSS transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)). >> this would be the `.row` in your example, but don't use `.row-fluid` as it will be absolutely positioned (it will mess up your `.col` widths).

There's a plethora of online content regarding sliders and carousels, you should check it out. You can also completely avoid the headaches and just go and use a JS library that will handle that for you.

In any way, I wouldn't rely on jQuery's `.scroll()` for left/right movement: this won't be handled well on mobile.

I would also recommend that you start with your mobile layout and extend it to larger viewports. Focus on the simplest UX possible and the rest will follow easily.

Also, making a responsive layout is *only* dealing with a couple of CSS breakpoints, you don't necessarily need Bootstrap for this.

Let me know if I need to clarify something! Good luck!